# Git / bash: Know if current branch is merging

Tags: git, bash, merge

Is there any way to know if the current branch is in *merging* status?

It means, is there any way to know if *MERGE_HEAD* exists?

I'm developing a script that will traverse several projects and I want to automatize some steps.

My idea is something like

```
# for each project
git checkout dev
git pull
git checkout $myBranch
git merge dev
if [[THERE_ARE_CONFLICTS]]
    echo "Some warning"
else
    git push origin $myBranch
fi;
```

Comment: Doesn't `git status` report that?

Comment: Could your script not just check for the existence of the `.git/MERGE_HEAD` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git merge` has a non-zero exit status if there are merge conflicts. That is, you can simply use

```
git merge dev
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "All fine."
else
   echo "There were merge conflicts."
fi
```

If you don't have access to the exit status, then checking for existence of `.git/MERGE_HEAD`, as kfb suggested in the comments, is a reliable way to detect that git is currently in merging status, as is documented briefly in the [git-merge man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> [..] record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD (to cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit) [..]

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific Git command for that. 
You can check the existence of the .git/MERGE* file.

```
git merge dev
if [ ! -z "$( ls .git/MERGE* 2>/dev/null )" ]; then
   echo "Merge is on-going"
else
   echo "All fine."
fi
```